# Imager plugin for watermarks

Tags: plugin-imager

First time using the Imager plugin and really unsure how to code it. Looking over the documentation I'm not clear on what the 'logo' is referring to to know what to change it to:

```
{ watermark: { image: logo, width: 80, height: 80, position: { right: 30, bottom: 30 }, opacity: 0.8, blendMode: 'multiply' } }
```

https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft

My attempt so far:

```
{% set imageWatermark = [{ watermark: { image: logo, width: 80, height: 80, position: { right: 30, bottom: 30 }, opacity: 0.8, blendMode: 'multiply' } }] %}

{% set transformedImages = craft.imager.transformImage(image, imageWatermark) %}

{# Output image #}
<img src="{{ asset.getUrl('transformedImages') }}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look a little further down in the Readme and you will see more information regarding Watermark.

From the Readme...

image: The image that is to be used as watermark. Just as the image parameter in the craft.imager.transformImage method, this can be an AssetFileModel, a string to a previously transformed Imager image, or a string to an external image.

```
{% set logo = craft.assets({ id: 11 }).first() %}
{% set watermarkedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, { 
    width: 600, 
    watermark: { image: logo, width: 80, height: 80, position: { right: 30, bottom: 30 }, opacity: 0.8, blendMode: 'multiply' }
}) %}
```

Also a link to a Watermark demo https://imager.vaersaagod.no/?img=6&demo=watermarks